# DataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added) fails with null values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

C#, WinForms, DataGridView, DataTable.  My form allows the user to enter data into a new row (as opposed to, say, popping up a single record view of the record).  When the user clicks my Save button, the click event looks like this:

```
DataTable dtAddRows = this.SomeFictitiouslyNamedDataSet.SomeFictitiouslyNamedDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
```

My assumption is that calling GetChanges with that enum is going to get me a set of the rows that were added to the grid at run time.  However, it errors out because 1 of the columns "Last_Updated_DT" (which must be displayed and readonly) is a date column that will be populated when we write to the datatable. However, the DataSet has a rule that this column cannot be null.

The problem is, I get an error indicating that the Last_Updated_DT column is actually null (surprise surprise).  Its a new row, and the column is readonly in the grid, so of course it is null.

How do I get around this error or stuff a value in that (or those) rows for that column before I actually try to get the added rows?

Comment: Does that line compile?  Or did you name your DataSet ... DataSet?  and your DataTable... DataTable?

Comment: You can set a default value to that read only column.  Your new rows will have that value instead of null.

Comment: @KiNeTiC Can I set a Default value of DateTime.Now?  This doesnt seem to work with anything other than text from the gui, and after Im in the click event, its too late.

Comment: No, but you can use the DataGridView DefaultValuesNeeded event to do it.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b22t666e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @KiNeTiC Thanks!  That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of posterity:

```
private void myGrid_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["MyColumnNameGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value = String.Empty;
}
```

Adding that event to my code fixed my issue.  I set the value to `String.Empty` so it wouldnt put a date/time value in the column until after the Save was clicked.

Then, in the `Save_Click` event, I get the added rows with this code:

```
DataTable dtAddedRows = this.dsMyDataSet.MyDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
```

Then, in the `TableAdapter.Insert` parameter list, I added `DateTime.Now` for the date parameter.

Eventually call `MyTableAdapter.Update` method using the `DataSet` overload.

All fixed.

Hat tip to @KiNeTiC for providing the necessary guidance.